# What does 'pisketti' mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

Here is the context.

> UH OH PISKETTI-OH, Donald Trump, that was not your plan, was it?

Is it a idiom or just a random exclamation without any special meaning?

I see it in this article.
[Hero Obama Judge will see Dumbass Trump Lawsuit Next Tuesday](https://www.wonkette.com/hero-obama-judge-will-see-trumps-dumbass-lawsuit-in-court-next-tuesday-no-literally)

Comment: Also [***uh-oh spaghetti-o's***](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=uh-oh%20spaghetti-o%27s) and other variants. Apparently just a meaningless "exclamation" made up of quirky and/or repeated elements (cf ***Fiddlesticks!, Botheration!,*** etc., and "minced oaths" such as spitting out ***Oh sugar!*** instead of ***Oh shit!***).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a play on the expression "Uh oh, SpaghettiOs," which comes from [a commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4iyEU8WKIE) for the [canned pasta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaghettiOs).

Essentially, it just means "Oops!".

From the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=uh-oh%20spaghetti-o%27s):

> An expression of regret over a goof: oops. From a 1970s TV commercial for Franco-American SpaghettiOs, a canned pasta dinner sometimes with meatballs or sliced frankfurters. Another Homer Simpson quote.

---

Here, *pisketti* is just a variation of [*pasghetti*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pasghetti), which is, itself, a simplified pronunciation of *spaghetti*. Children will often mispronounce the actual word so that it sounds like this.

Comment: +1 If you watch the video, at the very start the young girl actually says "Here come the pisghetti-os!".

Comment: Is "sk" any simpler than "sp"?  Surely just a spoonerism?

Comment: @jonathanjo It is easier to pronounce *sk* than *sp*, but it's the first two letters that make the change. It's much easier to pronounce *pa* than *sp*. The rest of the word follows how it starts.

Comment: @jonathanjo It is easier to pronounce *sk* than *sp*, but it's the first two letters that make the change. It's much easier to pronounce *pa* than *sp*. The rest of the word follows how it starts.

Answer (score 3):

Thre are multiple allusions here, which can be confusing. According to [Wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/pasghetti/pisketti) (and other sites) *pasketti* is a comm on childish mispronunciation of *spaghetti*. But what does  spaghetti have to do with it, one might ask? Well, several decades ago, there was a popular and long-running series of TV advertisements with the tag-line "Uh-oh Spaghetti-Os". These generally showed a child with his or her face smeared with Spaghetti-Os (a canned food product with small circular pasta in tomato sauce). The phrase became popular, being used to indicate some small but urgent problem.

By using this line, and combining it with a childish error for spaghetti , I suspect that the writer is trying to suggest that Trump's actions here are both childish, and likely try to create a mess that someone else will have to clean up. But it is a somewhat obscure allusion for anyone who does not remember the ad campaign involved.